# Regex - Stop processing immediately after first match

Tags: regex

For **performance reasons**, how can I **force Regex to stop processing the entire text** immediately **after the first match** is found?

I have tried '*non-greedy repeats*' and '*bounded repeats*' and even matching up to a *newline character* (\n), yet the entire set of text is processed and multiple matches are made!

Here is an example that demonstrates this:

Regex's that I tried:

```
Cookie: (.*)[\n]
Cookie: (.*){1}
Cookie: (.*)?
```

Text:

```
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: user=jdoe; fname=John; lname=Doe
CPU wasted processing this arbitrary text...
Cookie: ja_dravity_tpl=ja_dravity; utmz=22
Still wasting CPU on the entire string of text...
Cookie: user=msmith; fname=Mary; lname=Smith
```

Unfortunately, **all three 'Cookie:' lines are matched** which obviously means that the **entire string of text was processed**.

Here we can see what's actually going on: https://regexr.com/3iabj

**UPDATE**
Many thanks to gribvirus74 for pointing me in the right direction, this is how it is done in C++:

```
std::regex expression("Cookie: (.*)");
std::smatch results;

bool found = std::regex_search(str, results, expression);
if (found) {
    std::cout << results[0].str() << std::endl;  // entire matched string or
    std::cout << results[1].str() << std::endl;  // only the first submatch
}
else
    std::cout << "Not found." << std::endl;
```

Comment: Which flavor of regex are you using?

Comment: @CinCout, I'm using the Perl flavor available in C++11.

Comment: @CarolineBeltran You should post your edit as an answer and accept it (as mentioned by Cincout) so that future readers can easily find the answer. Although gribvirus74 brought you closer to the answer, it did not actually *solve* the problem and the answer thereby provided should be marked as a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the **g** flag from the regex. It will disable iterative searches.

Comment: And how might someone do that in C++?

Comment: @ctwheels, I updated my top post to answer your question.

Comment: @gribvirus74,interestingly, a 20k string of text that was processing in 332 microseconds is now processing in 65 microseconds!  Thank you!

Comment: @CarolineBeltran thank you for updating your own question! I'm sure it'll be appreciated by future readers

Comment: @CarolineBeltran I'd rather you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

To stop processing after the first match correctly and remove the '**g flag**' (which is not an option using `std::regex` in C++) you have to add the flag '`std::regex_constants::nosubs`' as shown in the following example:

```
std::regex expression("Cookie: (.*)", std::regex_constants::nosubs);
std::smatch results;

bool found = std::regex_search(str, results, expression);
if (found) {
    std::cout << results.size() << std::endl;  // returns always 1
}
else
    std::cout << "Not found." << std::endl;
```

If you want to improve further your performance, you can add the flag `std::regex_constants::optimize` at the expression declaration:

```
std::regex exp("Cookie: (.*)", std::regex_constants::optimize | std::regex_constants::nosubs);
```